# Deserializing Object

Tags: c#

In C# code, While Desearializing an object with the help of an customized deserialize class which checks the list of safe derializable types and returns the type to be deserialized, even if I pass a null value to the type to be deserialized, still my deserializing class returns the correct deserialized object Type.

below is the code snippet -

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

formatter.Binder = new SafeSerializeDeserializeData();

object temp = formatter.Deserialize(ReadStream);
```

I am not sure why does `temp` always have the valid type, even if I return null from `SafeSerializeDeserializeData` class. Not familiar with the deserialize Class or concepts.

Comment: What do you mean by the valid type?

Comment: By valid type I mean the Type to which the object is expected to get deserialize in. In my case, it is 'TcpExChannelData'.

Comment: **Because that's what you serialized.**  An `object` variable can hold objects of any type, and generally you would cast your deserialized object to the expected type anyway. It is likely that the serialization process preserves the metadata of the object, so on deserialization the `object` variable would already contain the correct type.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.2. for code examples.

Comment: What type are you **expecting** `temp` to have, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even if I return null from SafeSerializeDeserializeData class

If you return null, the deserializer will use the fallback type.

```
if (m_binder != null)
    type = m_binder.BindToType(assemblyString, typeString);
if ((object)type == null)
    type= FastBindToType(assemblyString, typeString);
```

Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryobjectreader.cs,1339).